# Omit comment replies from the minimum character limit check

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies, character-limit

Comments must be at least 15 characters long, which is supposed to make comments like "..." impossible to submit.

This works fine, however, there is a way around this, by using comment replies, even "fake" ones e.g. "@somelongname ...".

Can the system strip the comment reply part (e.g. "@somelongname") before performing the minimum characters check?